# Separate Flask routes for GET and POST methods

Tags: http, flask, routes

When defining routes in Flask, is it better practice to use a single route defined with multiple HTTP methods, and handle the different HTTP methods with explicit logic inside this single route, e.g.

```
@app.route("/api/users/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users():
if request.method == 'GET':
    ...
elif request.method == 'POST':
    ...
```

or define multiple routes with specific HTTP methods, thus avoiding any explicit HTTP request method logic inside each route, e.g.

```
@app.route("/api/users/", methods=['GET'])
def users_get():
    ...


@app.route("/api/users/", methods=['POST'])
def users_post():
    ...
```

Also, as Flask allows the GET HTTP method on all routes by default, what would be best practice for defining an additional route for a static resource? Should the HTTP method be stated explicitly, as in the first example in the preceding code snippet, or omitted and therefore implied, e.g.

```
@app.route("/api/users/")
def users_static():
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a lot of common code between how you handle the HTTP methods for a route, you can prefer the first way. If not, you can separate them out into different functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the first part of my question. Are you able to provide any thoughts on the second part?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just select one way and be consistent throughout.