# Separate Flask route GET method from POST

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a following route for file upload.

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    form = FileUploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file = form.document.data
        file_name = secure_filename(file.filename)
        save_path = get_user_uploads_folder(current_user) / file_name
            return redirect(url_for("upload_file"))
        file.save(save_path)
        return redirect(url_for("list_user_files"))
    return render_template("upload_file.html", form=form)
```

How to separate this route, so i can have *GET* and *POST* methods in different functions with common route like so:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET"])
def upload_file():
    return render_template(...)

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload_file():
    form = FileUploadForm()
    ...
    return redirect(...)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate Flask routes for GET and POST methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577212/separate-flask-routes-for-get-and-post-methods)

Comment: Each function must have a unique name. So rename at least one in your code and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in the Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods). You can use the following pattern:

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return do_the_login()
    else:
        return show_the_login_form()
```

Comment: I want to make a route function follow single responsibility principle. Assuming that, GET method logic should be processed separately from POST logic, so they cannot be in the same function.

Comment: That is the purpose of the `do_the_login` and `show_the_login_form` functions which are called from the route. Each has a single responsibility; the route is simply a wrapper.

Comment: Okay, how do i pass FileUploadForm from ```show_the_login_form```  to ```do_the_logic```?

Comment: You can instantiate the form in the route and then pass it into both functions.

Comment: My main goal is to get rid of this *if* condition, so i don't have to check for *request.method* inside a route. But i stuck on how to pass form from *GET* to *POST* to process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the methods in the request and then apply appropriate actions to it.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST')
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template(...)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(...)
    else:
         // do whatever you want here for exceptions
```